# Using AngularJS to compare piece of one array in order to return a piece of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, compare

I am having a problem where I am trying to have a piece of code look at a dynamic AngularJS variable {{ conn.branchId }}, which looks like this:

```
<li class="text-center">
           {{ conn.b-Id }} - {{ conn.rnk }}
</li>
```

Which is controlled by a controller, which looks like this:

```
GApi.execute('cloudpoints', 'webservice.get_conns', {
    'user_id': sessionService.get('user_id'),
    'user_token': sessionService.get('token')
}).then(function (response) {
     angular.forEach(response.items, function (item) {
            var user = new User();
            user.f_n = item.f_n;
            user.rnk = item.rnk;
            user.b-Id = item.b-Id;
 vm.cnctn.push(user);
```

Which reports a series of Ids, that I have matched in another piece of code which is here:

```
  var arm = {
  id:'B_T_A',
  name:'AM',
  seal:'AM-seal'
};
var m = {
  id: 'B_T_M',
  name:'M',
  seal: 'm-seal'
}; 
var n = {
  id: 'B_T_N',
  name:'N',
  seal: 'n-seal'
};
var af = {
  id: 'B_T_A',
  name: 'AF',
  seal: 'af-seal',
};
var cs = {
  id: 'B_T_CS',
  name: 'CG',
  seal: 'cg-seal'
};
var cv = {
  id: 'B_T_CV',
  name: 'CV',
  seal: 'cv-seal'
};
```

What I want the code to do is to compare the id provided by conn.b-Id with the array of variables I have made, and to give the name of var that it's Id matches (so, if conn.b-Id puts out an Id that matches the id of var cv, var cv's name will appear). This is what I wrote:

```
<li class="text-center">
          <script>  
            if ( {{ conn.branchId }} === ar.id) {
              return ar.name;
            } else if ( {{ conn.branchId }} === m.id) {
              return m.name;
            } else if ( {{ conn.branchId }} === n.id) {
              return n.name;
            } else if ( {{ conn.branchId }} === af.id) {
              return af.name;
            } else if ( {{ conn.branchId }} === cg.id) {
              return cg.name;
            } else {
              return cv.name;
            }
          </script> - {{ conn.rank }}
</li>
```

This doesn't work. How would I do this?

Comment: Im surprised you are not having your console blow up with errors. 

There are multiple places where you do this but `user.b-Id = item.b-Id;` is not valid Javascript since the `-` operator is reserved for subtraction operations and cannot be used for namespaceing.

Comment: The reason why the code looks like that is because I abbreviated all the terms that aren't operators - the actual code does not appear this way.